# ログインユーザの名前を取得

Tags: python, django

djangoでHTML上でログインユーザ名の取得を行いたいのですが、
カスタムユーザで認証をユーザ名からメールアドレスに変更した影響で
HTML上で`'user.username'`ないし`'user.get_username'`で取得される値はメールアドレスになってしまいます。

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

use_in_migrations = True

def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

    return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

コードはこのままの場合、ユーザ名を取得する方法はあるのでしょうか？

@追記
userモデルの定義（一部抜粋）

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
"""カスタムユーザーモデル."""

nick_name = models.CharField(_('ニックネーム'), max_length=20)

def get_full_name(self):
    full_name = '%s' % (self.nick_name)
    return full_name.strip()

def get_short_name(self):
    """Return the short name for the user."""
    return self.nick_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ユーザ名はどのフィールドに保存していますか？そのままアクセスすれば、値が表示されます。
たとえば、テンプレートに以下のコードでfirst_nameとlast_nameの値が表示されます。

```
request.user.first_name
request.user.last_name
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
指摘通りの記述で取得することができました。

また、モデル定義は追記しました